# How do the symmetries of a Lie manifold manifest in the metric tensor of that manifold?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, clifford-algebras

Suppose we have some Lie manifold (ie a Lie group) that is also a Riemannian manifold endowed with a metric tensor
How does the Lie group symmetry manifest in the properties of the metric tensor?

I would guess that the tensor locally adheres to the properties of the Lie algebra corresponding to the group in question, However I'm unclear precisely how this would manifest.

first thought is to lead with a decomposition of the gamma matrices. In physics one can decompose a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ into gamma matrices $\gamma_{\mu}$ such that:

$$Ig_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu}+\gamma_{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left\{ \gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}\right\} $$

Where I is the identity matrix. For the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ the commutator of the gamma matrices

$$\sigma_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu}-\gamma_{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}\right]$$

turn out to be the infinitesimal generators of the Lorentz transformations (ie elements of the group algebra). These can in turn be exponentiated to form the elements of the Lorentz Group:

$$T_{\nu}=exp(\theta^{\mu}\sigma_{\mu\nu})$$

In this case we can recover the group properties of the manifold from examining the properties of the metric tensor (or rather it's decomposition). What about a SU(2) (represented as the manifold of a 3-sphere) or a general Lie group? Does anyone know if the metric tensor carries these properties in general???

Any answer or direction towards a book that covers this subject would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A-priori I see no reason for the Lie group structure to play any kind of role which is connected to an arbitrary Riemannian structure. Perhaps you meant to assume the metric is left invariant?

Comment: @AsafShachar  Yes, failed to say that I assumed a left-invariant metric. I'm a physics student and unfortunately such things are often glossed over without explanation. apologies

Comment: @AsafShachar   Doesn't the metric tensor decompose into "gamma matrices" which themselves reproduce the group algebra (in this case Lie algebra) of the manifold in question? In the simple case of the minkowski metric the commutator (roughly speaking) of the gamma matrices form the generators of the Lorentz group (to give a  commonly encountered example). From there of course we can exponentiate and form the group elements (if I'm remembering correctly)

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean; I am not an expert on Lie algebras, so unfortunately I am not sure I can help. I do advise you to edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @AsafShachar   As suggested I've rewritten the question.  I'm just learning Lie groups myself and also Clifford algebras.