# How do lie symmetries manfest in the metric tensors of their manifolds?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, fourier-series

Suppose we are considering some pseudo-Riemannian manifold (spacetime) that has an underlying topology $SU(2)\times U(1)$ (which incidentally corresponds to a closed cyclic universe). Such a space is of course endowed with a metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. Then we should be able to represent the metric tensor of a general space satisfying this via the generalized Fourier series (Via the Peter-Weyl theorem I believe):

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\sum_{m}^{\infty}A(m)Y_{\mu\nu}^{m}(x^{i})$$

Where the series indices m will in actuality be summed over multiple indices (four I believe n,m,l,k for example all with conditions between them? it's not important for this question). How do the symmetries underlying the manifold (the initial Lie group) manifest in the terms of the series? Via the Peter-Weyl theorem I'm led to believe there's a connection of some kind. Note: I attempted to ask this in a [wholly different manner earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896794/how-do-the-symmetries-of-a-lie-manifold-manifest-in-the-metric-tensor-of-that-ma) but failed I believe in expressing the meat of my question. Also related: [What does it mean for something to be $L^2(G)$ for compact G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945106/what-does-it-mean-for-something-to-be-l2g-for-compact-g)

Comment: How is the metric tensor related to the Lie structure?

Comment: @JasonDeVito    That comment is basically a rewording of my question. Since one can, in principle, discern the topology of a manifold from the metric tensor (using contractions of the Riemann tensor for example), and the topology is furthermore indicative of its Lie group (assuming it is one of course), then there ought to be a way to relate the metric tensor to the group symmetry of the manifold. I just can't figure out how to get it going.